# fail2ban doesnt read log if file being used

Tags: ubuntu, networking, logging, fail2ban

My environment is Ubuntu 14.04, LAMP stack all from apt.

implemented fail2ban and configured `jail.local` with

```
backend = auto

[ssh]
enabled = true
port = ssh
filter = sshd
logpath = /var/log/auth.log
maxretry = 2
```

I am running `tail -f /var/log/auth.log`
and also `tail -f /var/log/fail2ban.log`
and wait.

Soon enough auth.log shows someone trying to get in, but no matter how many times the same ip tries - fail2ban will not ban it.

If i run `sudo service fail2ban restart` then i get stop and start INFO msgs in the fail2ban log , followed by all the detections it missed, and if not the time is according to the setup fail2ban *will* ban the ip as expected.

I did another test and closed the tail on auth.log - and not fail2ban seems to pick up the evil ip addresses.

Comment: Is that a typing mistake or you have it like this? `logpath /var/log/auth.log`. It should be `logpath = /var/log/auth.log`

Comment: Anything in the fail2ban logs? Please show `iptables -L -n`. What backend is set for fail2ban?